# This expression has type 'void' and can't be used

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse XML to JSON and for that I have used Xml2JSON package. When I am using this it is resulting me an error:

```
Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
```

Here is my code:

```
Xml2Json xml2json = new Xml2Json();
String json = xml2json.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking [the example in the docs](https://pub.dev/packages/xml2json#-example-tab-) for the plugin you're using, I believe that `.parse` methods returns `void`.

As the example shows, you should first `parse` and then transform to json with one of the different methods (`.toBadgerfish`, `.toGData()`, `toParker()`).

Hence, your code should be something like this:

```
Xml2Json xml2json = new Xml2Json();
xml2json.parse(data);
String json = xml2json.toBadgerfish();
```